# If number is greater than execute again

Tags: java, applet

I need this thing that if `deelgetal` is greater than 100, it needs to loop. and run the code again. Same if it's smaller than 10. I just don't know the code, anyone?

```
public void generate_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    double randomGetal = Math.random(); 
    int deelsom = (int)(20*randomGetal) + 1; 
    uitvoerveld2.setText(String.valueOf(deelsom));
    double randomGetal2 = Math.random(); 
    int answer = (int)(8*randomGetal) + 1;
    int deelgetal = (deelsom * answer); 
    uitvoerveld1.setText(String.valueOf(deelgetal));
    if (deelgetal > 100) {
      }
    if (deelgetal < 10) {
    } // end of if
  } // end of generate_ActionPerformed
```

Comment: How about a do-while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `do-while` loop and something like

```
int deelgetal;
do {
  double randomGetal = Math.random(); 
  int deelsom = (int)(20*randomGetal) + 1; 
  uitvoerveld2.setText(String.valueOf(deelsom));
  double randomGetal2 = Math.random(); 
  int answer = (int)(8*randomGetal) + 1;
  deelgetal = (deelsom * answer); 
} while (deelgetal < 10 || deelgetal > 100);
```

It isn't clear what variables you will need *after* your loop, move their declarations outside the loop as I did with `deelgetal` and you can preserve the ones you need.